# JQuery mouseover/mouseout Function - Better Code?

Tags: jquery

Is there a better way to write the Following code?

I am using Aloha Editor and in my jQuery, any elements with the class editable will get a 3px dashed border on mouseover, the code below is working fine, and I am just wanting to know if there is a "best practice or a better way" to write this code:

```
 $(function(){
  $('[class^="editable"]').mouseover(function(){
      $(this).css('border','3px dashed #a7a7a7');
  });
  $('[class^="editable"]').mouseout(function(){
      $(this).css('border','0px dashed #ffffff');
  });
});
```

Comment: why can't you use css :hover selector?

Comment: If you still want to use jQuery for this purpose then you can use `.hover` event. It takes two argument functions, one when cursor is over the element and one when cursor gets out. http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Comment: Thanks Guys, I didn't know this function, I appreciate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Avoid calling `$()` with the same selector twice by chaining the methods:

```
$('[class^="editable"]').mouseover(function(){
  $(this).css('border','3px dashed #a7a7a7');
}).mouseout(function(){
  $(this).css('border','0px dashed #ffffff');
});
```

And rather than adding specific CSS add those settings to your stylesheet as a class, and then add and remove the class:

```
$('[class^="editable"]').mouseover(function(){
  $(this).addClass('hovered');
}).mouseout(function(){
  $(this).removeClass('hovered');
});
```

(...where the default style for the element would be defined as per what you were setting in the mouse out.)

Comment: Smart answer, you keep the code and the styles in the files where they belong.

Comment: Thanks @JonathanRomer. Of course you can do it all in the stylesheet as per Blender's answer, though that doesn't work on all element types in old IE (assuming anyone still cares about IE6).

Comment: Is it because it is cleaner to add class in stylesheet then calling it in jQuery?

Answer (score 4):

I would do it with CSS:

```
[class^="editable"]:hover {
    border: 3px dashed #a7a7a7;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Best way to do it is CSS as its faster and more consitent regarding separation of styling and scripting also js is consuming your resources. But if you need to support IE6 or lower you can't use :hover :)

```css
.editable
{
   border: 0px dashed #fff;
}

.editable:hover
{
   border: 3px dashed #a7a7a7;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `hover`, which allows you to specify the second function as an argument, thus not selecting the element again:

```
$('[class^="editable"]').hover(function(){
    $(this).css('border','3px dashed #a7a7a7');
}, function () {
    $(this).css('border','0px dashed #ffffff');
});
```